# AngularJS - ng-repeat dynamic array value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I do if I am trying to combine 2 string values? For example `ng-repeat = "a in (name + 'List')"`. The name string value in this expression `allList`, `jonnyList`, `henryList`. How can I do that?

Example code:

```
<ul ng-repeat="a in name+List"> // i want if "name = 'all'", Return the values in allList.
    <li>{{a}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: post a fiddle or add some dummy data here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create function, which will return desired array as `$scope's` corresponding property:

```
$scope.dynamicArray = function(name){
    return $scope[name + 'List'];
}

<ul ng-repeat="a in dynamicArray(name)">
    <li>{{a}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Define a scope method that adds the "List" and then use this method in ng-repeat

```
$scope.getList = function(name) {
   return $scope[name + "List"];
};

<ul ng-repeat="a in getList(name)">
    <li>{{a}}</li>
</ul>
```